# Match partial backreference in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, backreference

I'm attempting to clean up a malformed JSON string using `regexp_replace` function.  I have a string like the following:

```
{ 0: {"foo": "bar", "baz": "24/05/2016", "qux": "12"}, 
  1: {"foo": "bar", "baz": "04/11/2015", "qux": "13"}, 
  2: {"foo": "bar", "baz": "25/07/2016", "qux": "14"}
}
```

In order to make this valid JSON, I need to wrap the keys, which are numeric, in double quotes.  I don't want to capture the existing numeric data in each nested object.

I initially thought to use a backreference, matching those numbers which are followed by a colon, but of course the captured backreference contains the colon, which I don't want to wrap in quotes.

```sql
regexp_replace("column_to_fix", '\d:', '"\&"', 'g') as "cleaned"
```

Will not quite do it, since each numeric key with colon `\d:` will get wrapped in quotes, rather than only the number.  conceptually, using python syntax, I'd like to replace matched with `"\&[-1]"` .  Is it possible to get a substring of the backreference?

The result I am working toward is:

```
{ "0": {"foo": "bar", "baz": "24/05/2016", "qux": "12"}, 
  "1": {"foo": "bar", "baz": "04/11/2015", "qux": "13"}, 
  "2": {"foo": "bar", "baz": "25/07/2016", "qux": "14"}
}
```

Comment: Try `regexp_replace("column_to_fix", '([0-9]+):', '"\1":', 'g')`

Comment: Perfect, capture group, thank you

Comment: Once these are cleaned up, consider changing the column type to [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) to take advantage of all the Postgres JSON functionality.

Comment: @Schwern that's the plan - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the string replacement pattern entities the way you want.

Use a capturing group instead and a corresponding backreference to it in the replacement pattern:

```
regexp_replace("column_to_fix", '([0-9]+):', '"\1":', 'g') as "cleaned"
```

Here, `([0-9]+):` will capture one or more digits into Group 1 and a colon will be just matched, and the matche(es) will get replaced with these digits in Group 1 inside double quotes and a colon will be appended to this substring.

Comment: Note there can be whitespace around the key: `(\d+)\s*:`. And if it's possible they're signed: `'([+-]\?\d+)\s*:'`. Finally, this might match inside JSON strings like `"th3:ree"`. There's no simple solution for that, but to to make it an error cast the result to `jsonb`. `regexp_replace(column, '([+-]?\d+)\s*:', '"\1":', 'g')::jsonb`

Comment: @Schwern If OP has issues using their approach (as it is now), the pattern can be further adjusted.